# tangent vs cotangent space and the derivative: intuition and an example

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm working through the first chapter of "An Introduction to Manifolds" by Tu and am drowning under formalism without a good sense of what is motivating the many definitions. I think a lot of my confusion stems from the fact that, for calculus on $\mathbb{R}^n$, I'm not used to keeping track of "where objects live" (point in manifold vs vector in tangent space $T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ vs vector in cotangent space, etc.). A specific point of confusion is the following:

Recall that a map $f:A\subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x_0\in A$ if there exists linear function $\mathbf{D}f(x_0):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, denoted the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$, such that
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{ f(x)-f(x_0)-\mathbf{D}f(x_0)\mathbf{(x-x_0)}}{x-x_0}=0.$$

I want to interpret this in the language of manifolds; specifically, where does the boldface $\mathbf{(x-x_0)}$ live? I know it lives in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but is it $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a manifold, tangent space, or cotangent space? From what I've read, the derivative in the context of differential geometry is a linear map between tangent spaces, suggesting that $\mathbf{(x-x_0)}\in T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. But this doesn't really make since to me since I conceptualize $\mathbf{x-x_0}$ as corresponding to an infinitesimal change in $x$ in limit (I know that's not rigorous), which I believe is formalized in the context of diff. geom. as the differential form $dx$, which lives in the cotangent space.

What am I missing? How exactly would one recast the definition of derivative found in a multivariate calculus book into one using the language of tangent spaces, differentials, etc.?

Comment: I like the Weierstraß formula for derivatives: $f(x_0+v)=f(x_0)+D_{x_0}(f)\cdot v + r(v)$ where all parts are displayed. The function $f$, the point $x_0$ that is on the manifold, and simultaneously the origin of the tangent space, the direction $v=x-x_0,$ the linear approximation $D_{x_0}(f)$ and the remainder $r(v),$ the error of the approximation. The direction lives in the tangent space. The problem with derivatives is, that you have dozens of perspectives, depending on what your variable is: $f\, , \,x_0\, , \,D\, , \,D_{x_0}\, , \,D(f)\, , \,D_{x_0}(f)\, , \,v.$

Comment: What you've written is wrong and makes no sense. You are inconsistent in your use of bold and non-bold letters, but, regardless, you cannot divide by a vector. This is a crucial difference between the multivariable derivative and the single-variable derivative. And no, a tangent vector $\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0$ is not at all identified with the dual notation of a differential vector.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are confused about some of the fundamental concepts, so let me recap. A map between manifolds is said to be differentiable if it induces a differentiable map between the corresponding coordinate charts (which is basically a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ so the usual definition of differentiability applies here). If you want to consider the linear map $Df(x_0)$ in the case of manifolds, then you will have to pick an interpretation of the *tangent space* of a manifold at a point. You can find multiple ways of defining the tangent space [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)). The idea is that instead of thinking of $x-x_0$ as we do in $\mathbb{R}^n$, one should consider the tangent vectors of a manifold at a point as *equivalence classes of curves*. This is the conceptualization of the “infinitesimal change” that you are looking for. Then the linear map, which is called the *differential* and should remind you the Jacobian, simply pushes those curves forward to create new *vectors* in the tangent space of the codomain of the map.

Answer (score -1):

$x - x_0$ denotes, in the limit, an infinitesimal change in a particular direction, i.e. a tangent vector at $x_0$. An "infinitesimal change to $x$ in limit", as you describe it, is one way to think of what a tangent vector is.

In general, you can recognise that something is a tangent vector if it is an input to $D(f)(x_0)$, also written as $D_{x_0}(f)$.
This is the differential map, so its inputs are tangent vectors, as are its outputs.